# c++ convert 2 dimensional char array const char**

Tags: c++, string, multidimensional-array, char

I have an function which takes const ** char as a function parameter. The input I have to call this function is a string which I need to convert to const char** where each row will be a single character of the string.

> "string" => {"s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"}

I was able to create a char** with the above data but converting it to const char** I couldn't do. Compiler obviously gave error. Then I created a 2 dimensional character array char input[string.size()][2]. But with this I am at lost on how to convert it to const char**

**UPDATE :** This did what I was looking for - (const char **)temp where temp is char[size][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a const_cast the type of your pointer.

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
 const char **const_av = const_cast<const char **>(av);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you have a `char**` (derived from
a `char *[]`?), and you want to assign it a `char const**` or
use it to initialize a `char**`.  This is illegal, as it would
break const:

```
char const s[] = "abc";
char const** p = s;
char** q = p;           //  illegal without const_cast
char* ps = *q;          //  because it allows this
*ps = 'x';
```

You should ask yourself what is really const here.  If you're
dealing with string literals, rather than:

```
char* s[] = { "abc", "123", "xyz" };
```

you may want:

```
char const* s[] = { "abc", "123", "xyz" };
```

or even:

```
char const* const s[] = { "abc", "123", "xyz" };
```

Alternatively, perhaps the function should take a `char const*
const*` (if it modifies nothing).  A `char**` will convert to
this implicitly.

Finally, if it's a legacy function, whose signature you cannot
modify, but which doesn't actually modify anything, you can use
`const_cast` to force the compiler to accept it.

Comment: I cannot modify the signature. But this did what I was looking for - (const char **)temp where temp is char[size][2]